# navigator.getUserMedia error

Tags: html, web, camera

I've enabled getusermedia at chrome://flags, but when it executes

navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);

it always go to video error.

why? any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try so

```
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia);

navigator.getUserMedia (


   {
      video: true,
      audio: true
   },function(...){...})
```

as I know getUserMedia still prefixed in Chrome